# Extract same file from multiple directories with same name i.e. 00000.gz?

Tags: server, gzip

Extract the file from multiple folders with same name into some other folder with diffrent name..

If possible with increasing count file1 to file100.

As of now if i run this command then it only saves one file which includes content of last file extracted in last folder.

```
for d in ./*/ ; do 
    (cd "$d" && for f in *.gz ; do gunzip -c "$f" > /home/$USER/awss3extract/"$f" ; done); 
done
```

Comment: From my understanding you have e.g. files `./dirA/00001.gz` and `./dirB/00001.gz`, right? What should be the result when you unzip both of them to the directory `$HOME/awss3extract`? What names should they have in this case?

Comment: You can use `seq` to generate sequences of numbers, or `find` to get a list of files, or `bash`'s`$((` arithmetic. Please explain: are all the files in the `*.gz` named the same?